# Parsing a Gemfile.lock with Bundler

Tags: ruby, api, rubygems, bundler

Basically, I'm trying to build a gem that does some form of test failure when certain dependencies are outdated. In the testing framework I can easily stub the crap out of Gem so that Gem.loaded_specs("foo") returns the spec for the gem foo. What I'm looking for is a way to provide a fixture Gemfile and then parse the lock file.

When I use Gem.loaded_specs it somehow magically knows which Gemfile to use, how do I feed it a different gemfile (ie: my fixture)?

I know somebody mentioned "use bundler" and that makes sense but in my code for the gem I do this:

```
gem_here = Gem.loaded_specs[gem_name]
gem_here.nil? ? :not_in_bundle : gem_here.version.to_s
```

I need to make this work with my fixture Gemfile and not the current projects gemfile.

Does this make any sense? Sorry if this is vague.

Note: I'm not trying to do this via the CLI. I'd like to use programmatic (ie: ruby api) methods if I can.

Edit:

I'm going with this kind of source now:

```
gem_here = Bundler.load.specs.detect do |specs|
  specs.name == gem_name
end
gem_here.nil? ? :not_in_bundle : gem_here.version.to_s
```

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you may find what you need in the source of https://github.com/appfolio/gemsurance

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom thanks! That actually helped a lot. I'll post the answer if I get to it but so far Bundler.load led me to Bundler::SharedHelpers.default_gemfile

Comment: Still stuck. I might have to just knuckle down and parse the file using regexes. Not a great solution but the fastest / most direct way to parse. :-(

Comment: Source: 

```
    gem_here = Bundler.load.specs.detect do |specs|
      specs.name == gem_name
    end
    gem_here.nil? ? :not_in_bundle : gem_here.version.to_s
  end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parsing yourself isn’t desirable as Bundler does the heavy-lifting (parsing, dependency resolution).

`Bundler::LockfileParser.new(Bundler.read_file(Bundler.default_lockfile))`

Then, use gemspecs and the lockfile to visit all runtime and/or development dependencies. Runtime/development deps for specific gems are available via a (currently undocumented, needs contrib) RubyGems JSON API https://api.rubygems.org/api/v2/rubygems/rails/versions/5.0.0.1.json

**Note:** Bundler 2.0 `Gemfile.lock` -> `gems.locked`

Comment: Thank you so much! This is basically what I was looking for so I could run tests against a Gemfile of specific type (not the one for my own code)

Comment: The file itself is not a YAML file, although each section of it might be. `yaml = YAML::load(File.open('Gemfile.lock'))` gives me `Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 9`

Comment: @iconoclast True. It’s an opaque file and the format is irrelevant to the answer. It may resemble YAML now, but it could easily change and that’s Bundler’s responsibility. Updated. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: This is really cool. You can then easily iterate over all the data, e.g. `.specs` will give you the current installed gems according to the lockfile, each entry there can be accessed with `.name` and `.version`.

```ruby
parser = Bundler::LockfileParser.new(Bundler.read_file(/path/to/Gemfile.lock')
parser.specs.each { |name, version| puts name; puts version } 

```